# superset Invalid login. Please try again

Tags: apache-superset

i installed superset in aws ec2 follwed this link https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch/ after 2 months the server was down and i restarted the machine but i am getting the error while login as admin it shows me **Invalid login. Please try again.**
i am using the same credentials and checked for typo also please help.
i need dashboards also and pleSe help with the backup of all those thanks.
i am using default db in .superset/superset.db i didt changed anything but creds was wrong

Answer (score 5):

Reinitiliase the database to recreate the users table.

```
superset db upgrade
superset fab create-admin  . # To create admin user.
superset init  # Create default roles and permissions
```

Answer (score 1):

There are steps provided under section **"Initialize a local Superset Instance"** in the following link
https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset

Answer (score 0):

Use this to resolve the problem

```
flask fab  list-users  ## To view all the users
flask fab  reset-password   ## To reset user password
```

Comment: logging was configured successfully
2022-02-18 05:21:36,258:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2022-02-18 05:21:36,265:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:201: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn(
List of users
-------------
i am getting that but thanks i analysed all my supersetdb but no table found for users i think my db was corrupted